# How to determine count of array dimensions?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, autoit

How to determine count of array dimensions?

You can't loop any dimension (without error) if you don't know if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

From the Help File:

```
UBound ( Array [, Dimension] )
Array The array variable which is being queried. 
Dimension [optional] Which dimension of a multi-dimensioned array to report the size of. Default is 1, which is the first dimension. If this parameter is 0, the number of subscripts in the array is returned.
```

Considering the above:

```
Local $myArray[10][20] ;element 0,0 to 9,19

For $i = 1 To UBound($myArray, 0)
    ConsoleWrite("Dimension: " & $i & " :" & UBound($myArray, $i) & @LF)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

> Yeah, I know, that AutoIt isn't the best when you have to work with complex data or big programs with modules

Wrong but let's stay on topic ;)

Let's use a 2D array for an example.

To get the row count, use

```
$iRowCount = UBOUND($array)
```

To get the column count, use

```
$iColCount = UBOUND($array, 2)
```

Need total size?

```
$iTotal = UBOUND($array) * UBOUND($array, 2)
```

EDIT: Anything bigger? Loopit

```
Local $iTotal = 1
For $i = 1 To UBOUND($array, 0)
    $iTotal*= UBOUND($array, $i)
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

> "... *determine count of dimensions.*"

Example as per [Documentation - Language Reference - `UBound()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/UBound.htm) :

```
#include <AutoItConstants.au3>; $UBOUND_DIMENSIONS

Global $g_aArray[1]
ReDim $g_aArray[3][6][9]

ConsoleWrite('Array comprises ' & UBound($g_aArray, $UBOUND_DIMENSIONS) & ' dimensions.' & @CRLF)
```